# Storing JSON variable in django database

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my app that uses Gridster I am changing the widget positions and then saving it as a json variable.I want to store this json variable in django database.
For that I am not understanding how should I define a function in views.py and a class in models.py which can store the json variable

My HTML/JS template is

```
var URL = "{% url 'my_view_url' %}";

   $('.js-seralize-update').on('click', function () {

            var s = gridster.serialize();
            updated_grid=JSON.stringify(s);
            $('#log').val(updated_grid);

            function updategridster(){
            var data = updated_grid;
            $.post(URL, data, function(response){
            if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
            else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });
}

        });
```

My views.py

```
def save_grid(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

            # Some code to get json variable and store it to model
            return HttpResponse('success') # if everything is OK
```

I want to write some kind of class in models.py corresponding to view.py so that JSON variable can be saved

**Edit1**
My models.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils import simplejson as json

class update_grid(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I just want to send data from views to this model(If it is correct)

**Edit 2**

My JS Script is updated as follows

```
  var URL = "{% url 'save-grid' %}";

     $('.js-seralize-update').on('click', function () {

                var s = gridster.serialize();
                updated_grid=JSON.stringify(s);
                $('#log').val(updated_grid);

                function updategridster(updated_grid){
                var data = updated_grid;
                $.post(URL, data, function(response){
                if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
                else{ alert('Error! :('); }
        });
    }
                 updategridster(updated_grid);          
            });
```

Now I get this error

```
 POST http://localhost:8000/calendar_grid/save-grid net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED  jquery.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the built in [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) if you use PostgreSQL.

Otherwise there are several implementations like [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield), for admin i pair this with [django-jsoneditor](https://github.com/nnseva/django-jsoneditor)

Then you can save the JSON data in a single field, and in the case of the built in, you can even do queries/filter on specific keys inside the JSON structure.

Comment: And then how should be corresponding views.py so that variable can be stored in models.py

Comment: are you asking how you set a modefield? you use `model_instance.fieldname = value` then `model_instance.save()`

Comment: I mean what should I write in place of      `'# Some code to get json variable` and store it to model in my views.py so that variable will be passed to class in models.py

Comment: I am using sqllite builtin database

Comment: you can get post-data with `request.POST.get("post-variable-name")`

Comment: Something like this ?                                             `if request.method == 'POST':

            request.POST.get(data)
            return HttpResponse('success')   `    data is variable name in URL

Comment: Is my way of passing variable to database perfect/correct ?

Comment: No you need to make or get a model first, then set its value. your model should not be named update_grid but UpdateGrid, then you can get it with `mymodel = UpdateGrid.objects.get(...)` and then run `mymodel.data = json_data` and `mymodel.save()`. This is usually done with a `ModelForm`. This is covered in the tutorial on the django website which i recommend you to go over.